# Getting value from a @Html.TextBox with javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Does anyone have an idea why doesn't this work? I do not know what I can do, I appreciate it from someone who knows I'm doing wrong.
Error:

> "getTipe" does not exist.

```
<div class="modal-body">
   <p>
      @Html.TextBox("newTipe", null, new { @class = "form-control" })  
   </p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>                                                      
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "TipeService", "Edit", new { tipe = getTipe }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function getTipo() {
       return $("#newTipe").val();
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear that tells you there is no variable with named `getTipe`. So, you want to grab get parameter of the action link in the client side. You should change your approach. You could assign a `onclick` event to `ActionLink` and add the get parameters in the `href`.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "TipeService", "Edit",new { @onclick="getTipo(this)", @class = "btn btn-success" })

   function getTipo(actionLink) {
       var val = $("#newTipe").val();
       $(actionLink).attr('href', $(actionLink).attr('href') + '?tipe=' + val);
   }
```

Comment: @samuel Sai, doesn't the answer satisfy the requirement ?

Comment: It did not work, it does not manage to get the value of the textbox, I do not know why.

Comment: I do not know why, but , that load the function in the browser bar, look: http: // localhost: 2188 / Edit / TipeService? Onclick = getTipe28this% 29

Comment: I have just tested it, there is no problem. In somehow, your actionlink couldn't trigger onclick event.

Comment: i fix it, the code loaded it as a path value instead of an attribute., now I have another problem and it is that I do not load '/' between the information that the event takes and the href, it loads it practically followed by the "TipeService" , and in the code I tried to add a '/' before '? tipe' and the only thing I get is this: http: // localhost: 2188 / List / NaN? tipe = abc

Comment: ready and it works for me, sorry for stealing your time, I greatly appreciate your contribution